# PHP: How to detect if a certain class has constructor?

Tags: php

How do i detect of a certain class has constructor method in it? eg:

```
function __construct()
{
}
```

Comment: I think __construct is PHP5 syntax, not? Maybe the tags should be corrected then (removal of php4)

Comment: Why do you need to know? it does not affect the ability to make a new instance. You could always consult the PHPDocs.

Comment: but if the method is in fact private it does affect this ability, but then i don't know how to check it.

Comment: Or the example be changed to reflect php4 behaviour

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [method_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) I suppose ?

Answer (score 5):

```
function hasPublicConstructor($class) {
    try {
        $m = new ReflectionMethod($class, $class);
     if ($m->isPublic()) {
         return true;
     }
    }
    catch (ReflectionException $e) {
    }
    try {
     $m = new ReflectionMethod($class,'__construct');
     if ($m->isPublic()) {
         return true;
     }
    }
    catch (ReflectionException $e) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

Using method_exists() can have it's pros, but consider this code

```
class g {
    protected function __construct() {

    }
    public static function create() {
     return new self;
    }
}

$g = g::create();
if (method_exists($g,'__construct')) {
    echo "g has constructor\n";
}
$g = new g;
```

This will output "g has constructor" and also result in a fatal error when creating a new instance of g. So the sole existance of a constructor does not necessarily mean that you will be able to create a new instance of it. The create function could of course return the same instance every time (thus making it a singleton).

Answer (score 4):

There's a couple ways, and it sort of depends on exactly what you're looking for.

[method_exists()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) will tell you if a method has been *declared* for that class.  However, that doesn't necessarily mean that the method is *callable*... it could be protected/private.  Singletons often use private constructors.

If that's a problem, you can use [get_class_methods()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php), and check the result for either "__construct" (PHP 5 style) or the name of the class (PHP 4 style), as `get_class_methods` only returns methods that can be called from the current context.

Answer (score 1):

Reflection API expose isInstantiable()

```
  $reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($class);
  echo "Is $class instantiable?  ";
  var_dump($reflectionClass->IsInstantiable());
```